# "Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '‘Event' is not a valid attribute name." Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

[image]

I recently just pulled my project and after running the npm install, and serving, i get no compile error, but when i visit the url, it keeps reloading forever and throwing this erorr which is hard to trace.

Answer (score 0):

In other to trace this error, hover on the error message and you will see a stack trace of the error. something like "at {component name} line ##.##" this is often due to typo errors in the view.